# Gradle. pass parameters to dependent project build script

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have project ("backend") configuration:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':model') //I would like to pass some params into this being build.
    ...
```

And other project ("frontend") configuration is very similar:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':model') //but from this project I will not pass params.
    ...
```

And when I build the dependant project model- I need to pass a parameter to it's build parameter and do something on condition. So for all projects who needs the sub-projects it will be built according to their needs.

To be more specific: When I build "backtend" - "model"'s project should run some task, but when I build "frontend" I don't.

Is it possible to force clean the sub-project as well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can easily pass parameters from command line, or by properties defined in `gradle.properties` or in `ext`. Here's a little project:

**/build.gradle**

```
ext {
    var = "alpha"
}

task hello {
    println "Name: $project.name"
    println "Var: $var"
    println "Param: $param"
    println "Prop: $prop"
}
```

**/gradle.properties**

```
prop=gama
```

**/settings.gradle**

```
project.name = 'foo'

include 'bar'
```

**/bar/build.gradle**

```
task hello {
    println "Name: $project.name"
    println "Var: $var"
    println "Param: $param"
    println "Prop: $prop"
}
```

If you run `gradle hello -Pparam=beta` it will print:

```
Name: foo
Var: alpha
Param: beta
Prop: gama
Name: bar
Var: alpha
Param: beta
Prop: gama
:hello UP-TO-DATE
:bar:hello UP-TO-DATE
```

Comment: Can I add this property from the main build script? not from command line?

Comment: Sure, using the `ext {}`. But maybe describe your use case a bit more. There might be a different way.

Comment: Seems like $ is no longer required in Gradle 4.